# How do i add objects into an array from a Class in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

This is my Friend class:

```swift
class Friend {
    var firstName: String = ""
    var lastName: String = ""
    var age: Int = 0
    var description:String = ""

    init(firstname: String, lastname: String, age: Int) {
        self.firstName = firstname
        self.lastName = lastname
        self.age = age
    }
}
```

This is where i'm supposed to declare and instantiate 5 `Friend` objects in the viewDidLoad function and to add them into 'friendList' array.

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var friendsList: [Friend] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        friendsList.append("John", "Doe", 20)
    }
}
```

Swift tells me that "No exact matches in call to instance method 'append'" on the "friendsList.append" line.

Comment: Nothing in your code creates `Friend` objects, you'll have to do that somewhere.

Comment: You could create your `Friend` inside the append function for instance: `friendsList.append(Friend(firstname: "John", lastname: "Doe", age: 20))`

Answer (score 0):

you can use like Below if you are creating all friends Initially

```
 let friends = [Friend(firstname: "John", lastname: "Doe", age: 20),Friend(firstname: "doe", lastname: "John", age: 21)]
    
    for friend in friends{
        friendsList.append(friend)
    } 
//////////////////////////////////////
 (or) you can directly declare value for your global variable  

friendsList = [Friend(firstname: "John", lastname: "Doe", age: 20),Friend(firstname: "doe", lastname: "John", age: 21)]
///////////////////////////////////////////

(or) assign local variable value to your global variable
friendsList = friends
```

or if you adding One by One,You have to create object first

```
  let friendOne = Friend(firstname: "John", lastname: "Doe", age: 20)
    friendsList.append(friendOne)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Array (Actually collection) function append takes a parameter of type `<T>` where `T` is a generic type, "the type of the elements in the array".

So if you have an array of Strings, you need to pass a String into append:

```
var strings = [String]()

strings.append("a string")
```

Since you have an array of `Friend` objects, you need to pass an instance of `Friend` to the `append(_:)` function. Does the expression inside the parentheses in your call to append evaluate to a friend object?

```
friendsList.append("John", "Doe", 20)
```

It doesn't. You'r passing a comma-separated list of properties. Presumably, those are the first name, last name, and age of a `Friend`, but the `append()` function doesn't know that.

You could write it as:

```
let aFriend = Friend(firstname: "John", lastname: "Doe", age: 20)
friendList.append(aFriend)
```

Or all in one line with:

```
friendList.append(Friend(firstname: "John", lastname: "Doe", age: 20))
```

Both of those variations would work.